# P2P File Transfer c#

Tags: p2p, transfer

Hey, basically I want to send files to my friends through a program, I have been looking on google but I can't seem to find anything.

I have found [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/peer_to_peer_communicator.aspx) but it is for C++ and i'm looking for C#

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks.

Comment: Brilliant, i'll have a look thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh boy.. Sooo many ways to do this :)

You could use one of the many WCF bindings for this purpose, but it requires .Net 3.5, which I don't think is a problem.

Here's an example using the very basic TCP-binding: 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/wcffileserver.aspx

Comment: woops, commented on the wrong thing haha: Brilliant, i'll have a look thanks!

Comment: I have my own site, do you know of any guides that is the same but using a remote server?

Comment: Not sure I understand :) You have your own "site", as in, your own server? :) Http? Ftp? If so, why not just use a ftp-client? :P

Comment: Ftp and Http, You have the right idea with an ftp-client, but this gives them full access to my site. And I want to make it so they only have access to a certain folder.